# How to vectorize my function without using iterrows()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to vectorize this code as I read in other stackoverflow questions that iterrows should not be used when going through data (and I was mostly using them and apply).
The functionls `matchTimeWithStops` and `calculateTheDelay` were not vectorized before. I would get 30mins, but when i vectorized them my code runs for 4 minutes.

I wonder if I can do better? The only thing that I think is left to vectorize is the first for when I am going through every line in a dataframe which is very big (900MB in .csv).
I tried using list comprehension but somehow I need to call the functions and store the variables. I also tried using apply but I couldn't figure it out.

`matchTimeWithStops` uses an int as a line and vehicle_row uses one single row as a dataframe. Then I only extract three values from it (I can change the function).

`calculateTheDelay` uses the returned value from `matchTimeWithStops` which is a dataframe and also needs the vehicle_row.

At the end the result is an integer (delay)

I hope you can help me

```
for number in [95,2,3,4]:
    line, vehicles = getLineAndVehicle(number)
    vehicles = vehicles[vehicles['DistanceFromPoint'] == 0] # get only the vehicles that are on the stop 

    total_delays = []
    
    for index, vehicle_row in vehicles.iterrows(): # go through each bus that is on the stop
        delays = matchTimeWithStops(line, vehicle_row) # get the delays from the matched possible stoptimes for that vehicle in that line
        if delays.empty != True: # avoid when it doesn't find anything
            final_delay = calculateTheDelay(delays, vehicle_row)
            total_delays.append(final_delay)
        else:
            total_delays.append(None)

    vehicles['delay'] = total_delays
```

Comment: The most painless way would be to reformulate the task using `apply` instead of  `iterrows` and then try `swifter` (https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter). There's a high chance it will bring about a significant speedup, all for mere couple minutes of work. If it doesn't, then start looking elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe you could use numba.